# Jave: regex for a term

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have a grammar

```
NxC
```

N is a multi digit positive number, C are characters between "A" and "Z", x is the character "x".

x and C are optional. C must have a predecessor x.

Valid input would be:

```
01
9x
789xAUX
```

I would do a regex:

```
([0-9]+)(x?)([A-Z]*)
```

But with that also this would be valid.

```
123ABC
```

Thats not what I want. C is only allowed if x is in place.

How can I change my regex to get this?

Comment: There [have been](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13132262/3832970) lots of such [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47396693/3832970).